# how to find i class of active buttons using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a vertical button group (bootstrap) and I need a function to find which buttons are active (have active class) and create an array that includes the i class of the active button . The button group looks like this:-

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth"><i class="icon-rss"></i> news</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth active"><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i> opinion</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth active"><i class="icon-lightbulb"></i> research</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth"><i class="icon-signal"></i> stats</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth active"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> how to...</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth"><i class="icon-desktop"></i> platform/app</button>  
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth"><i class="icon-cloud"></i> tool</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn customwidth"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i> uncategorised</button>    
</div>
```

This function would be triggered by clicking any of the buttons.

Any idea how I would do this please.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [];
$('button.active').each(function(){ arr.push($('i', this)[0].className) });
```

or

```
var arr = $('button.active i').map(function() { return this.className }).get();
```

Comment: that's great, sorry about this, but how could I change this so that it loops through all buttons in the group and creates the array using a function such as arrayofallselectedbuttons() for example

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. My answer loops through all `.active` buttons. And the array of all `.active` buttons is simply `$('button.active')`. What do you want different ?

Comment: sorry - I'm an idiot!! Thanks, it didn't seem to be getting the first clicked button but I have it figured out now - thanks so much!!!

Comment: umm sorry, it still doesn't add the current button's i class as I think there is a delay in setting the active class on button click - any ideas? thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var array = [];
    $('.btn-group-vertical').find('button.active > i').map(function(){
        array.push(this.className);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/AUZDy/8/)

Comment: it works with the exception that it doesn't add the current button's i class to the array, any ideas? Maybe because the active class is added after the click function has finished?

Comment: http://monkeygetnews.jonathanlyon.com/indextest.php the issue is also evident when you unclick a button http://monkeygetnews.jonathanlyon.com/indextest.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function dystroysFunction()
{
    return $('button.active i').map(function() { return this.className }).get();
}

setTimeout(function(){dystroysFunction()},1000);
```

I'm using dystroy's code (+1 for him, obviously) combined with setTimeout to help you.